# How can I get into Linux Mint system not recognizing my password?

Tags: password

I installed Linux Mint 12 and I am sure of my password, but it does not agree with me and "incorrect password number of successful attempts; system halted must power down"
How can I get into the system to see what's happened or to make a change?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Questions that are about Linux Mint and not about Ubuntu [are off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions). You should instead ask this somewhere Linux Mint is supported, like the [Linux Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/) or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

at boot select the 'recovery mode' option and boot to a root shell.

From there type

```
passwd your_username
```

(where you substitute 'your_username' with your actual username) and set a new password for your account.